# Custom Payment Gateway with external redirects in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

1. The customer selects a custom payment method
2. When 'Place Order' is clicked, the customer is redirected to the external payment page with some additional POST data
3. Payment page redirects on success/failure
   back to a specified Magento controller, which processes the result